# Instance vs Class variables and Random Numbers Ruby

Tags: ruby, variables, random, instance

Hello I am writing a code for a simple die of (n) sides and it works fine:

```
class Die

  def initialize(sides)
    @sides = sides
    raise ArgumentError if sides < 1 
  end

  def roll
    roll_number = rand(@sides) + 1
  end
end
```

However, when I change my initialized variable from instance to class the random numbers generated go from integers to a bunch of small floating point numbers around 1.

```
class Die

  def initialize(sides)
    HERE --> @@sides = sides
    raise ArgumentError if sides < 1 
  end

  def roll
    roll_number = rand(@sides) + 1
  end

end
```

I wanted to know what may cause this difference?

Answer (score 1):

In the second code snippet, you're initializing the class variable `@@sides` but still passing the instance variable `@sides` to `rand()`. Since `@sides` is not initialized, you are passing `nil` to the call to `rand()`, so [Kernel#rand](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) gives a float instead of integer.

Answer (score 0):

There's an error in your code, in your second version of `Die` you actually never call the right variable in your `roll` method.

It should be:

```
  def roll
    roll_number = rand(@@sides) + 1
  end
```

Instead yours was evaluating to:

```
roll_number = rand(nil) + 1
```

According to the [`rand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-rand) library if you don't supply an argument rand returns a pseudo-random floating point number between 0.0 and 1.0, including 0.0 and excluding 1.0.